# Obtain expiration date / details about a WCF ssl certificate from .net client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ssl

From my .net client code, is there a way to obtain details about an SSL certificate being used by a WCF service? Assuming I can already connect successfully over SSL to the service.

I am hoping to report the expiration date of the server certificate on a dashboard. If the certificate has been updated / renewed since the last time the client communicated with the service, I'm trying to detect that as well.

Let's also assume the server cert is a real public cert from godaddy etc. i.e. the cert would not have been explicitly imported into the client store already.

Any thoughts? I was thinking I might find somewhere in System.ServiceModel.ClientBase that I could find this after opening a connection but haven't found anything yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way would probably be to just implement a certificate validation callback on the client so that you can have a chance to look at the SSL certificate provided by the server before it is trusted by the client:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702579(v=vs.110).aspx